# Transform/parse javascript object key value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, object, transform

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "KeyValueOfstringstring": [
        {
            "Key": "FET",
            "Value": "123"
        },
        {
            "Key": "FFS2",
            "Value": "Z"
        },
        {
            "Key": "LoadIndex",
            "Value": "91"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Ply",
            "Value": "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i want it to look like this:

```
{
    "KeyValueOfstringstring": [
        {
            "FET": 123,
            "FFS2": "Z",
            "LoadIndex": "91",
            "Ply": "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

Has anyone done this before or has any idea how this could be accomplished? Unfortunately this is the response from a WS and thus have to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a regular `for` loop:

```
var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < object.array_with_long_name.length; i++) {
    var o = object.array_with_long_name[i];

    result[o.Key] = o.Value;
}
```